# Is it normal for screed to be laid on sharp sand?

Tags: flooring

I've had to dig up some pipework in a 1970/80s house (in the UK). The screed layer (the top layer) appears to be have been laid on about an inch of sharp sand. Is this normal? If so why? Just curious really, I normally expect buildings to be as solid and sturdy as possible, not sure why screed would be laid on something so unstable. The central heating pipework appears to be laid in the sharp sand, is the reason to allow a little movement when the pipes expand and contract?

UPDATE - right at the bottom is rock-hard concrete, then about an inch of what appears to be sharp sand, then about 2-3 inch of screed.

As far as I can tell the pipes were laid when the house was built. It may be that the what I've described as 'sharp sand' is in fact a very, very dry, weak and friable layer of screed.

Comment: to clarify: you have screed right over top sand? No slab or other sub floor? Screed is for levelling and finishing not structure. Usually the house is stabilized by its foundation and slabs are anchored to it. Sand under slab is common. Please clarify/confirm.

Comment: Were the heating pipes added after the home was built?  It sounds to me like someone hastily screeded a new floor over top of the original one in order to cover those pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tubing, such as heating, water or sewage pipes embedded in concrete must be wrapped in tape or plastic, or sleeved with plastic tubing. This provides insulation if needed, and -as you allude to- mechanical decoupling for expansion.

Such decoupling is not required in sand. Buried pipes are embedded in sand, covered by plastic, and covered by concrete slab.

If the screed is sufficiently thick -at 30mm or more-, it can second as an unbonded slab overtop a stable and strong substrate of sand & slab.